# Como fazer um sistema de movimentação utilizando touch no unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, touch

Ao deslizar o dedo para cima tela executa o comando e ao deslizar o dedo para baixo executa o comando, um exemplo de comando seria um movimento para cima e uma movimento para baixo com o touch me retornar um tipo `bool` `true` ou `false`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode testar as posições:

```
        //Variáveis de controle
        bool up    = false;
        bool down  = false;
        bool left  = false;
        bool right = false; 

        if (touch.y < Screen.height / 4) {
            Debug.Log ("Para Baixo"); //Aqui você seta a variável para TRUE
            transform.Rotate (Vector3.right, 2);
        }  else if (touch.x < Screen.width / 2 && touch.y > Screen.height / 4 && touch.y < (Screen.height - (Screen.height / 4))) {
            Debug.Log ("Para Esquerda"); //Aqui você seta a variável para TRUE
            transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, 2);
        }  else if (touch.y > Screen.height - (Screen.height / 4)) {
            Debug.Log ("Para cima"); //Aqui você seta a variável para TRUE
            transform.Rotate (Vector3.left, 2);
        }  else {
            Debug.Log ("Para Direita"); //Aqui você seta a variável para TRUE
            transform.Rotate (Vector3.down, 2);
        }
```

Ao mover para qualquer direção você tem a variável `True`, é possível ainda implementar para saber se esta movimentando para as diagonais, basta testar os 2 deslocamentos simultaneamente!

**Editado conforme sua edição da pergunta**

Script básico para facilitar o entendimento:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MoveTouch : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float speed = 1.5f;

    //Controle de Zoon
    private Vector2 v2_current_Distance;
    private Vector2 v2_previous_Distance;
    private float f_comfort_zone;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1;
    private GameObject go;

    //Controle de Rotaçao
    private Vector2 firstPressPos;
    private Vector2 secondPressPos;
    private Vector2 currentSwipe;

    void Start ()
    {
        go = GameObject.Find ("target");
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        if (Input.touchCount == 2 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved && Input.GetTouch (1).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
            v2_current_Distance = Input.GetTouch (0).position - Input.GetTouch (1).position;
            v2_previous_Distance = ((Input.GetTouch (0).position - Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition) - (Input.GetTouch (1).position - Input.GetTouch (1).deltaPosition));

            //Funçao Zoon
            float touchDelta = v2_current_Distance.magnitude - v2_previous_Distance.magnitude;

            if (touchDelta <= 1) {
                mScaleFactor = transform.localScale.x;
                mScaleFactor *= 0.9f;
                transform.localScale = new Vector3 (mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
            }

            if (touchDelta > 1) {
                mScaleFactor = transform.localScale.x;
                mScaleFactor *= 1.1f;
                transform.localScale = new Vector3 (mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
            }  
        } else if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {
            Vector2 touchDeltaPosition = Input.GetTouch (0).deltaPosition;
            go.transform.Translate (touchDeltaPosition.x * speed * Time.deltaTime, touchDeltaPosition.y * speed * Time.deltaTime, touchDeltaPosition.y * speed * Time.deltaTime); 

        } else if (Input.touchCount == 1 && Input.GetTouch (0).phase == TouchPhase.Stationary) {
            Vector2 touch = Input.GetTouch (0).position;

            if (touch.y < Screen.height / 4) {
                Debug.Log ("Para Baixo");
                transform.Rotate (Vector3.right, 2);
            }  else if (touch.x < Screen.width / 2 && touch.y > Screen.height / 4 && touch.y < (Screen.height - (Screen.height / 4))) {
                Debug.Log ("Para Esquerda");
                transform.Rotate (Vector3.up, 2);
            }  else if (touch.y > Screen.height - (Screen.height / 4)) {
                Debug.Log ("Para cima");
                transform.Rotate (Vector3.left, 2);
            }  else {
                Debug.Log ("Para Direita");
                transform.Rotate (Vector3.down, 2);
            }           
        }       
    }
}
```

Anexando esse Script em qualquer `GameObject` você o controlara para todas as direções, detalhe, você precisa gerar o `APK`, pois, observe que não possui nenhum controle de mouse ou teclado!

Faça os teste, e é de fácil implementação da primeira parte da resposta que postei!

Comment: eu testei, e não funcionou no caso teria que passar um parâmetro para reconhecer esse movimento na tela.

Comment: Na verdade amigo, esse teste é para exatamente o que você descreveu na pergunta, e não um controle de movimento. Serve de você já tem um sistema de movimento, que deu a entender na sua pergunta.

Comment: acho que me expressei mal, queria implementar o touch no unity pois eu não tenho um sistema de movimentação, se você achar melhor eu abro outra pergunta e deixo essa como teste de movimentação.

Comment: Não precisava abrir outra pergunta amigo, bastava editar esta!

Comment: ok vou editar essa valeu

Answer (score 0):

Se preferir usar como o input do direcional com suavidade, a intensidade você pode mudar de acordo com o tamanho da tela assim quando chegar ao y = -1 ou 1 atribuiria o valor para top e down e semelhante para x left e right,

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;

    public class Usatouch : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private Vector2 StartPos ;
        private Vector2 TouchDir ;
        public int intensidade = 200; 
        void Update()
        {
            touchupdate();
            horizontal = Mathf.Clamp(TouchDir.x/intensidade,-1,1);
            vertical = Mathf.Clamp(TouchDir.y/intensidade,-1,1);

        }
        void touchupdate()
        {
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
            {
                Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
                switch(touch.phase)
                {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    StartPos = touch.position;  
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    TouchDir = touch.position - StartPos;
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Ended:  
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

}
```